# Blender 2.78 VSE : How to display keyframes presence?

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor, keyframes

I'm using the VSE and adding keyframes for opacity, it's working.

The only place I can see if there is keyframes on my timeline is by moving the cursor on the timeline and looking in the Edit Strip menu for Opacity bar to change color.

How can I display visual indications of the presence of keyframes on my video strips? Or where can I find a panel where I can find all my keyframes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the keyframes in Dope Sheet, Graph Editor and NLA Editor.